# Cacluate Total Time in same table rows in Mysql

Tags: mysql, time, report

I have a design a table for attendance and here are the genral fileds

1. AttendanceMachineLoginId
2. EmpId
3. AttendanceDateTime

Whenever user will come to office, he has to make his attendance. The **first** attendance will consider **login** and the **second** will consider the **logout**. **Each time a record will be added with the time**. A user can make **multiple entries** (login logout in a single day.  Like this
[image]

EmpId 81 has login and logout two times in same day.

Now, My aim is to generate per day employee report that how many minutes he has given to the company. I just came to know that `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` can provide  the minutes but i am unable to understand that how can I apply it to my table. Additionally, I want to ask that, do the **table Fields** are right for the desired report or  I need to change it?

**One Another Strategy:** I was also thinking that I should add minutes column in the table and whenever user logout I should calculate the minutes and add that minutes with logout entry.

Here is the Sample Data For testing:

```
INSERT INTO `attendancemachinelogin` (`AttendanceMachineLoginId`, `EmpId`, `TimeTrackId`, `AttendanceDateTime`, `RecordAddDateTime`) VALUES
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 14:8:46', '2018-08-15 14:09:25'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 14:20:38', '2018-08-15 14:21:17'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 14:21:9', '2018-08-15 14:21:47'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 14:28:37', '2018-08-15 14:29:16'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 14:28:58', '2018-08-15 14:29:36'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 14:36:42', '2018-08-15 14:37:21'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 15:36:34', '2018-08-15 15:37:13'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 15:52:39', '2018-08-15 15:53:17'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 16:5:38', '2018-08-15 16:06:17'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 16:6:50', '2018-08-15 16:07:29'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 16:8:49', '2018-08-15 16:09:29'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 16:18:28', '2018-08-15 16:19:08'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 16:20:49', '2018-08-15 16:21:28'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 16:23:18', '2018-08-15 16:23:58'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 16:24:3', '2018-08-15 16:24:42'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 16:24:47', '2018-08-15 16:25:26'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 16:24:58', '2018-08-15 16:25:37'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 16:25:54', '2018-08-15 16:26:33'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 16:56:47', '2018-08-15 16:57:27'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-15 17:37:53', '2018-08-15 17:38:32'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-15 18:4:34', '2018-08-15 18:05:14'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-15 18:7:43', '2018-08-15 18:08:22'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-15 18:13:15', '2018-08-15 18:13:54'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 10:50:16', '2018-08-17 10:50:54'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 10:51:54', '2018-08-17 10:52:31'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 11:45:16', '2018-08-17 11:45:54'),
(0, 91, 916086, '2018-8-17 11:59:34', '2018-08-17 12:00:12'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 12:0:19', '2018-08-17 12:00:56'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 15:7:41', '2018-08-17 15:08:17'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 15:9:54', '2018-08-17 15:10:32'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 15:10:9', '2018-08-17 15:10:45'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 15:10:23', '2018-08-17 15:10:59'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 15:10:25', '2018-08-17 15:11:02'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 15:11:6', '2018-08-17 15:11:43'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 15:11:15', '2018-08-17 15:11:52'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 15:11:17', '2018-08-17 15:11:54'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 15:11:32', '2018-08-17 15:12:09'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 15:12:32', '2018-08-17 15:13:09'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 15:35:33', '2018-08-17 15:36:10'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 15:41:58', '2018-08-17 15:42:34'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 15:42:17', '2018-08-17 15:42:54'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 16:8:25', '2018-08-17 16:09:01'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 16:8:32', '2018-08-17 16:09:08'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 16:8:53', '2018-08-17 16:09:30'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 16:9:20', '2018-08-17 16:09:57'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 16:10:16', '2018-08-17 16:10:53'),
(0, 36, 413037, '2018-8-17 16:10:46', '2018-08-17 16:11:23'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 16:22:21', '2018-08-17 16:22:58'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 16:22:45', '2018-08-17 16:23:21'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 16:23:12', '2018-08-17 16:23:49'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 16:23:35', '2018-08-17 16:24:12'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 16:44:4', '2018-08-17 16:44:42'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 16:44:22', '2018-08-17 16:44:58'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 17:6:51', '2018-08-17 17:07:28'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 17:7:8', '2018-08-17 17:07:45'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 17:7:52', '2018-08-17 17:08:28'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 17:9:25', '2018-08-17 17:10:02'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 17:9:46', '2018-08-17 17:10:22'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 17:10:6', '2018-08-17 17:10:42'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 17:10:24', '2018-08-17 17:11:01'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 17:10:39', '2018-08-17 17:11:15'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 17:10:47', '2018-08-17 17:11:24'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 17:10:58', '2018-08-17 17:11:35'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 17:11:10', '2018-08-17 17:11:46'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 17:11:31', '2018-08-17 17:12:09'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 17:40:40', '2018-08-17 17:41:18'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 17:41:23', '2018-08-17 17:41:59'),
(0, 36, 413037, '2018-8-17 17:41:37', '2018-08-17 17:42:14'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 17:42:9', '2018-08-17 17:42:45'),
(0, 3, 213020, '2018-8-17 17:47:34', '2018-08-17 17:48:11'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 17:48:16', '2018-08-17 17:48:52'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 17:48:59', '2018-08-17 17:49:36'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 17:49:59', '2018-08-17 17:50:36'),
(0, 36, 413037, '2018-8-17 17:52:36', '2018-08-17 17:53:13'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 17:52:53', '2018-08-17 17:53:29'),
(0, 6, 213016, '2018-8-17 17:53:30', '2018-08-17 17:54:06'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 17:53:44', '2018-08-17 17:54:20'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 17:54:27', '2018-08-17 17:55:03'),
(0, 3, 213020, '2018-8-17 17:54:49', '2018-08-17 17:55:27'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 17:55:23', '2018-08-17 17:56:00'),
(0, 36, 413037, '2018-8-17 17:58:33', '2018-08-17 17:59:10'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 17:58:47', '2018-08-17 17:59:24'),
(0, 102, 517094, '2018-8-17 17:59:4', '2018-08-17 17:59:40'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 17:59:33', '2018-08-17 18:00:09'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 18:0:16', '2018-08-17 18:00:52'),
(0, 3, 213020, '2018-8-17 18:0:40', '2018-08-17 18:01:17'),
(0, 6, 213016, '2018-8-17 18:1:30', '2018-08-17 18:02:06'),
(0, 36, 413037, '2018-8-17 18:26:24', '2018-08-17 18:27:01'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 18:26:38', '2018-08-17 18:27:14'),
(0, 6, 213016, '2018-8-17 18:27:9', '2018-08-17 18:27:45'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 18:27:24', '2018-08-17 18:28:00'),
(0, 102, 517094, '2018-8-17 18:27:38', '2018-08-17 18:28:14'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 18:28:13', '2018-08-17 18:28:49'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-17 19:36:49', '2018-08-17 19:37:26'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-17 19:37:17', '2018-08-17 19:37:54'),
(0, 102, 517094, '2018-8-17 19:37:30', '2018-08-17 19:38:07'),
(0, 36, 413037, '2018-8-17 19:38:13', '2018-08-17 19:38:50'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-17 19:38:54', '2018-08-17 19:39:32'),
(0, 3, 213020, '2018-8-17 19:39:58', '2018-08-17 19:40:35'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-18 10:21:26', '2018-08-18 10:22:03'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-18 10:30:23', '2018-08-18 10:31:09'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-18 10:31:46', '2018-08-18 10:32:27'),
(0, 102, 517094, '2018-8-18 10:32:15', '2018-08-18 10:32:53'),
(0, 6, 213016, '2018-8-18 10:32:44', '2018-08-18 10:33:22'),
(0, 3, 213020, '2018-8-18 10:33:23', '2018-08-18 10:34:03'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-18 10:42:49', '2018-08-18 10:43:27'),
(0, 101, 417092, '2018-8-18 10:43:25', '2018-08-18 10:44:03'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-18 10:48:51', '2018-08-18 10:49:30'),
(0, 102, 517094, '2018-8-18 10:49:9', '2018-08-18 10:49:49'),
(0, 81, 315079, '2018-8-18 10:56:46', '2018-08-18 10:57:25'),
(0, 1, 1211003, '2018-8-18 10:57:0', '2018-08-18 10:57:38'),
(0, 4, 413034, '2018-8-18 10:57:51', '2018-08-18 10:58:38'),
(0, 3, 213020, '2018-8-18 10:58:43', '2018-08-18 10:59:26');
```

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What if someone forgets to logout

Comment: Yes this is a good question. In this case i will add a dummy record with 6pm time.

Comment: But how will you know whether it was a login or a logout that was forgotten?

Comment: This could be a simple variation of row_number simulation where the odd row numbers are the logins and the even row numbers logouts it would help (ie I cannot be bothered to retype) if instead of an image  you add sample data as text.

Comment: @Strawberry oh Thanks, this is also a very valid point.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have added the sample data as well.

Comment: @Strawberry do you have a better solution for this? It on inital phase i can change the table fields

Comment: Well, if it was operationally possible, I think I would want to have a column that recorded whether it was a login or a logout

Comment: @Strawberry Ok i will try to add it. Actually I can add it through the machine but each time a person has to set the machine check-in or check-out mode. But still i am searching for reporting. will it be possible by adding this login/logout column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmpId, DATE(AttendanceDateTime), SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(RecordAddDateTime, AttendanceDateTime))))
FROM attendancemachinelogin
GROUP BY EmpId, DATE(AttendanceDateTime)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd5f95/7

Comment: This is the solution to a different problem!?!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I have to go out but here's a partial solution using row number simulation and mod (%)

```
select x.*,y.empid,y.attendancedatetime,y.rn
from
(
select a.* ,
        if(a.empid <> @p, @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
        @p:=a.empid p
from   `attendancemachinelogin` a
cross join (select@rn:=0,@p:=0) r
order by empid,AttendanceDateTime
) x
left join
(
select a.* ,
        if(a.empid <> @p1, @rn1:=1,@rn1:=@rn1+1) rn,
        @p1:=a.empid p
from   `attendancemachinelogin` a
cross join (select@rn1:=0,@p1:=0) r
order by empid,AttendanceDateTime
) y
on x.empid = y.empid and y.rn = x.rn+1
where x.rn % 2 > 0;

+--------------------------+-------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+------+-------+---------------------+------+
| AttendanceMachineLoginId | EmpId | TimeTrackId | AttendanceDateTime  | RecordAddDateTime   | rn   | p    | empid | attendancedatetime  | rn   |
+--------------------------+-------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+------+-------+---------------------+------+
|                        0 |     1 |     1211003 | 2018-08-18 10:57:00 | 2018-08-18 10:57:38 |    1 |    1 |  NULL | NULL                | NULL |
|                        0 |     3 |      213020 | 2018-08-17 17:47:34 | 2018-08-17 17:48:11 |    1 |    3 |     3 | 2018-08-17 17:54:49 |    2 |
|                        0 |     3 |      213020 | 2018-08-17 18:00:40 | 2018-08-17 18:01:17 |    3 |    3 |     3 | 2018-08-17 19:39:58 |    4 |
|                        0 |     3 |      213020 | 2018-08-18 10:33:23 | 2018-08-18 10:34:03 |    5 |    3 |     3 | 2018-08-18 10:58:43 |    6 |
|                        0 |     4 |      413034 | 2018-08-17 11:45:16 | 2018-08-17 11:45:54 |    1 |    4 |     4 | 2018-08-17 16:10:16 |    2 |
|                        0 |     4 |      413034 | 2018-08-17 16:23:12 | 2018-08-17 16:23:49 |    3 |    4 |     4 | 2018-08-17 17:07:52 |    4 |
|                        0 |     4 |      413034 | 2018-08-17 17:10:06 | 2018-08-17 17:10:42 |    5 |    4 |     4 | 2018-08-17 17:40:40 |    6 |
|                        0 |     4 |      413034 | 2018-08-17 17:48:59 | 2018-08-17 17:49:36 |    7 |    4 |     4 | 2018-08-17 17:49:59 |    8 |
|                        0 |     4 |      413034 | 2018-08-17 17:54:27 | 2018-08-17 17:55:03 |    9 |    4 |     4 | 2018-08-17 17:55:23 |   10 |
|                        0 |     4 |      413034 | 2018-08-17 18:00:16 | 2018-08-17 18:00:52 |   11 |    4 |     4 | 2018-08-17 18:28:13 |   12 |
|                        0 |     4 |      413034 | 2018-08-17 19:38:54 | 2018-08-17 19:39:32 |   13 |    4 |     4 | 2018-08-18 10:31:46 |   14 |
|                        0 |     4 |      413034 | 2018-08-18 10:57:51 | 2018-08-18 10:58:38 |   15 |    4 |  NULL | NULL                | NULL |
|                        0 |     6 |      213016 | 2018-08-17 17:53:30 | 2018-08-17 17:54:06 |    1 |    6 |     6 | 2018-08-17 18:01:30 |    2 |
|                        0 |     6 |      213016 | 2018-08-17 18:27:09 | 2018-08-17 18:27:45 |    3 |    6 |     6 | 2018-08-18 10:32:44 |    4 |
|                        0 |    36 |      413037 | 2018-08-17 16:10:46 | 2018-08-17 16:11:23 |    1 |   36 |    36 | 2018-08-17 17:41:37 |    2 |
|                        0 |    36 |      413037 | 2018-08-17 17:52:36 | 2018-08-17 17:53:13 |    3 |   36 |    36 | 2018-08-17 17:58:33 |    4 |
|                        0 |    36 |      413037 | 2018-08-17 18:26:24 | 2018-08-17 18:27:01 |    5 |   36 |    36 | 2018-08-17 19:38:13 |    6 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-15 14:08:46 | 2018-08-15 14:09:25 |    1 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-15 14:20:38 |    2 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-15 14:21:09 | 2018-08-15 14:21:47 |    3 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-15 14:28:37 |    4 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-15 14:28:58 | 2018-08-15 14:29:36 |    5 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-15 14:36:42 |    6 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-15 15:36:34 | 2018-08-15 15:37:13 |    7 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-15 15:52:39 |    8 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-15 16:05:38 | 2018-08-15 16:06:17 |    9 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-15 16:06:50 |   10 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-15 16:08:49 | 2018-08-15 16:09:29 |   11 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-15 16:18:28 |   12 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-15 16:20:49 | 2018-08-15 16:21:28 |   13 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-15 16:23:18 |   14 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-15 16:24:03 | 2018-08-15 16:24:42 |   15 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-15 16:24:47 |   16 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-15 16:24:58 | 2018-08-15 16:25:37 |   17 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-15 16:25:54 |   18 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-15 16:56:47 | 2018-08-15 16:57:27 |   19 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-15 18:13:15 |   20 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 10:50:16 | 2018-08-17 10:50:54 |   21 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 12:00:19 |   22 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 15:07:41 | 2018-08-17 15:08:17 |   23 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 15:11:32 |   24 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 15:12:32 | 2018-08-17 15:13:09 |   25 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 15:35:33 |   26 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 15:41:58 | 2018-08-17 15:42:34 |   27 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 15:42:17 |   28 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 16:08:25 | 2018-08-17 16:09:01 |   29 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 16:08:32 |   30 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 16:22:21 | 2018-08-17 16:22:58 |   31 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 16:23:35 |   32 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 16:44:04 | 2018-08-17 16:44:42 |   33 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 17:06:51 |   34 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 17:09:25 | 2018-08-17 17:10:02 |   35 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 17:10:24 |   36 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 17:10:39 | 2018-08-17 17:11:15 |   37 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 17:11:10 |   38 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 17:42:09 | 2018-08-17 17:42:45 |   39 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 17:48:16 |   40 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 17:53:44 | 2018-08-17 17:54:20 |   41 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 17:59:33 |   42 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-17 18:27:24 | 2018-08-17 18:28:00 |   43 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-17 19:36:49 |   44 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-18 10:30:23 | 2018-08-18 10:31:09 |   45 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-18 10:42:49 |   46 |
|                        0 |    81 |      315079 | 2018-08-18 10:48:51 | 2018-08-18 10:49:30 |   47 |   81 |    81 | 2018-08-18 10:56:46 |   48 |
|                        0 |    91 |      916086 | 2018-08-17 11:59:34 | 2018-08-17 12:00:12 |    1 |   91 |  NULL | NULL                | NULL |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-15 17:37:53 | 2018-08-15 17:38:32 |    1 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-15 18:04:34 |    2 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-15 18:07:43 | 2018-08-15 18:08:22 |    3 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-17 10:51:54 |    4 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-17 15:09:54 | 2018-08-17 15:10:32 |    5 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-17 15:10:09 |    6 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-17 15:10:23 | 2018-08-17 15:10:59 |    7 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-17 15:10:25 |    8 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-17 15:11:06 | 2018-08-17 15:11:43 |    9 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-17 15:11:15 |   10 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-17 15:11:17 | 2018-08-17 15:11:54 |   11 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-17 16:08:53 |   12 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-17 16:09:20 | 2018-08-17 16:09:57 |   13 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-17 16:22:45 |   14 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-17 16:44:22 | 2018-08-17 16:44:58 |   15 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-17 17:07:08 |   16 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-17 17:09:46 | 2018-08-17 17:10:22 |   17 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-17 17:10:47 |   18 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-17 17:10:58 | 2018-08-17 17:11:35 |   19 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-17 17:11:31 |   20 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-17 17:41:23 | 2018-08-17 17:41:59 |   21 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-17 17:52:53 |   22 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-17 17:58:47 | 2018-08-17 17:59:24 |   23 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-17 18:26:38 |   24 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-17 19:37:17 | 2018-08-17 19:37:54 |   25 |  101 |   101 | 2018-08-18 10:21:26 |   26 |
|                        0 |   101 |      417092 | 2018-08-18 10:43:25 | 2018-08-18 10:44:03 |   27 |  101 |  NULL | NULL                | NULL |
|                        0 |   102 |      517094 | 2018-08-17 17:59:04 | 2018-08-17 17:59:40 |    1 |  102 |   102 | 2018-08-17 18:27:38 |    2 |
|                        0 |   102 |      517094 | 2018-08-17 19:37:30 | 2018-08-17 19:38:07 |    3 |  102 |   102 | 2018-08-18 10:32:15 |    4 |
|                        0 |   102 |      517094 | 2018-08-18 10:49:09 | 2018-08-18 10:49:49 |    5 |  102 |  NULL | NULL                | NULL |
+--------------------------+-------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+------+-------+---------------------+------+
59 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Good try i will try it.